# dynamic input box present within Form, loosing focus with typing single character

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am new to react and I need to achieve following:

**Requirement**

1. my application will have 1 config file.

```
"my-extension": {
            "TitleVariables": [
                {"label": "Product Code", "name": "-ot-productcode"},
                {"label": "Product Name", "name": "-ot-productname"}
            ],
           
        }
```

2. based on the config file values react application will create mandatory input boxes. while input box label will be driven by config file label attribute and ID will be driven by config file name attribute.
3. for mandatory input box I am using antd form input box.
4. finally on submit i need to generate following output:

```
"titleVariables": [{"variableName":"-ot-productcode","variableValue":"1"},{"variableName":"-ot-productname","variableValue":"2"}]
```

While variable values are the input box values.

**what i did**

- following is the line of code to get the input boxes based on config files:

```
const InputTitleVariables = () => {

        const buttonbarString: any = [];
        if (TitleVariables != null && TitleVariables?.length > 0)
        {
            setCount_ConfigInputBoxwithValues(TitleVariables?.length);
            TitleVariables.forEach((TitleVariable, index) => {buttonbarString.push(
            <div>  
              
               
                <Form.Item id={TitleVariable.name} className={styles.prodInput} name={TitleVariable.label} label={TitleVariable.label+" : : "} rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                    <Input id={TitleVariable.name} name={TitleVariable.label} className={styles.prodInputText} value="Provide Replacement value" 
                    onChange={(e) => handleProdCodeChange(e,index,TitleVariable.name,TitleVariable.label)}/>

                    {/* onChange={(e)=>{
                        setinputTextvaluesToReplace((prevConfigInputBoxValue) => {
                            return {
                              ...prevConfigInputBoxValue,
                              [index]: '{"variableName":"'+inputBoxID+'","variableValue":"'+e.target.value+'"},',
                            };
                        });
                    }} */}
                </Form.Item>
                
                
            </div>
            )});
    
           
            
        }
        return buttonbarString;
    }
```

- following is the handleProdCodeChange method:

```
const [inputTextvaluesToReplace, setinputTextvaluesToReplace] = useState({});

const  handleProdCodeChange = (e: { target: { value: SetStateAction<string>; }; },index: number, inputBoxID:string, inputBoxLabel:string) => {
        //  Store the input value to local state
        
        setinputTextvaluesToReplace((prevConfigInputBoxValue) => {
            return {
              ...prevConfigInputBoxValue,
              [index]: '{"variableName":"'+inputBoxID+'","variableValue":"'+e.target.value+'"},',
            };
        });
         
    };
```

- Following is the rendering section with html:

```
<Form key="replacementValues"
                                                {...layout}
                                                style={{ maxWidth: 350 }}
                                                autoComplete="off"
                                                >
                                                    <InputTitleVariables/>
                                                </Form>
```

**Problem**
I got the proper rendering of input boxes
on submit i can capture the input box values based on setinputTextvaluesToReplace

But the problem is the typing within the input boxes.

as soon as i try to type a character focus went back to the Form node.

**What i have tried**
I have tried with autofocus on input box. setting unique key attribute but behavior remain same.

Any help will be appreciated.